# How to install django-static-sitemaps on windows

Tags: python, django

I am using windows server for development and I am trying to install django-static-sitemaps. I used pip install django-static-sitemaps but it is giving me this error:

```
"Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\xx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jzlzgeur\django-static-sitemaps"
```

I want to install it on my windows machine. what is the alternate way to install. 
By the way I contacted the developer and here is his reply: https://github.com/xaralis/django-static-sitemaps/issues/30#issuecomment-73851787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you asked the owner of the project who couldn't even assist with this question.   You may be better off trying to go a different route. if your sitemap is huge and you don't want to use django's default sitemap builder, than you could look to implement something discussed in this answer.

[How to efficiently serve massive sitemaps in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807647/how-to-efficiently-serve-massive-sitemaps-in-django)

Basically they are setting up a cron job to execute the sitemap and cache the results.  This can be setup as a daily, weekly, hourly etc...

Comment: Thanks Chris, I saw that post. But that was almost 3 years old. So, I thought that there should be some better way of handling sitemaps. Also I am using latest version of django and python. So, I thought maybe that might not work for me.

Also there is a link provided in the post. But that link is no more working :(

Comment: To be honest I was just researching it for a site that i have, http://www.noobmovies.com.  It has about 25,000 pages or so and it's sitemap is way too slow.  This solution seemed to be the best bet according to my research.  If you find something else please let me know :)

Comment: I have a site with more than 500K products and it keeps growing on daily basis. So, it will not work for me. Because I have created sitemap index. So, I don't know exactly how many sitemaps will be there. So, I can set a fixed cron job for this :/